External Microsoft users in Azure stuck in login loop when attempting to access SharePoint site
For the past 6 weeks or so we’ve had an issue with External users getting stuck in an MFA loop. At first, it appeared to be users that had a Microsoft account (Outlook.com or Hotmail.com). Then it was just Microsoft accounts. Other external accounts seem to work fine. Yahoo and Gmail and other mail sources work fine. It just seems to be Microsoft accounts.
I set up an external test account using an Outlook.com email address and invited this test account to be a member of a SharePoint site using my domain account. After configuring MFA it is stuck in a loop.

Click next and one of two things happen. You're prompted to set up MFA and once configured, you get a success screen, but clicking 'done' loops you back to the 'More information required' window - repeat again. If you already have MFA configured, it just goes into a loop between attempting account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com URL and login.microsoftonline.com URL and switches back and forth between the two URLs for about 10-15 cycles then brings you back to a 'We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.' login screen.
Clicking 'Skip for now' will take you directly into the shared site, but that only works for 14 days.
When checking the sign in logs in Azure the status column shows 'interrupted.' When performing a sign on diagnostic on this event it returns the following:
Error Code: 50072
Message: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access".
Action: The user was presented options to provide contact options so that they can do MFA.
We have re-created the 'Guest User MFA' conditional access policy a couple of times. I even tried removing the conditional access policy altogether, but that didn't work.
Something else worth mentioning is that we had been working on an Multi-Tenant Organization connection with our new parent company, but couldn't get it working correctly so we removed it. I fear it may be remnants of this that has caused all this headache.
I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Did you ever manage to resolve this? I have the exact same issue and would appreciate any tips :)

Apologies, I should have added this when the case with Microsoft had been concluded:
It's a known issue if guest user accounts are included in both trust MFA for External users and Identity Protection MFA registration policy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/cross-tenant-access-overview#organizational-settings
I excluded quest users from Identity Protection MFA registration policy.
Microsoft is aware of this issue and as of 5/2024 it's in the pipeline to be addressed.
